# What is the difference between 見つける and 探す

Tags: word-choice, meaning

I think they have a same meaning: find or search. Could you help me to show the differences between them ? In the detail cases ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(～を)見つける means "to find ~~".

(～を)探す means "to look for ~~".

e.g.

> **探した**けれど、ミーちゃんを**見つける**ことはできませんでした。
>   We looked for Mii-chan, but we couldn't find her.

Comment: 確かに。 "I've found it!!!" → 「見つけた！！」だけど「探した！！」とは決して言いませんね。

Comment: Hmm, what about [this](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E6%8E%A2%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%9F%E3%81%82%E3%81%AE%E6%9B%B2) then? Can you even say 見つけた about something that doesn't have a physical form?

Comment: @kuchitsu Yes, I think you can. To say like "I found the song that I've been looking for", then you can say 「探していた曲を見つけた。」,「探していた曲が見つかった。」 (or you might just exclaim 「あった！」), etc... (Other examples: 「答えを見つける/が見つかる」「誤り/間違いを見つける」「タバコを吸っているところを先生に見つかる」Σ(ﾟ∀ﾟﾉ)ﾉｷｬｰ）