# Difference between 見つける and 発見する

Tags: word-choice, wago-and-kango

I would like to know the difference between 見つける and 発見する

Some partial answer has been given in:

> (～を)見つける means "to find ~~". Source: 
>   [What is the difference between 見つける and 探す](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33799/what-is-the-difference-between-%e8%a6%8b%e3%81%a4%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b-and-%e6%8e%a2%e3%81%99)

But I found some sentences where both have been translated as "find"

> わたしはあくまでも彼女を**見つける**つもりです。 I will definitely find her.
>
> ＫＴビル４階で対象を**発見**しました I found the target on the fourth floor of the KT
>   Building.

Are they equivalent or is there a slight difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically another [wago-and-kango](/questions/tagged/wago-and-kango) problem. 発見 is a much bigger and stiffer word used in scientific, military or other serious business contexts. You should not use 発見 in everyday casual conversations unless a joke is intended.

Comment: Perhaps it's meant as a joke, but for example saying 大発見 is not so rare in everyday casual conversations.

Comment: @Ben 大発見 may be a little more common than "great discovery", but it's basically a humorous and exaggerated expression in casual conversation.